# PostgreSQL view to read another table, transform data and return results

Tags: java, postgresql, view, pljava

Could some please suggest the best way to implement this:

Essentially what I want to have is a virtual-table in PostgreSQL that when queried, it looks up the data from some other table (call this the raw-data table). But the catch is, the data from the raw-data table needs to transformed, and when done so, the results are returned as if it were in the original table.

I will explain with illustrations and an example (not my real program, but just a simplified example to explain the main things I need):

**Raw-data Table**

```
| id (int) | data (byte[]) |
----------------------------
|   ...    |      ...      |
|   ...    |      ...      |
```

**Person Table (virtual table)**

```
| name (varchar) | address (varchar) | phone (varchar) |
--------------------------------------------------------
|       ...      |        ...        |       ...       |
|       ...      |        ...        |       ...       |
|       ...      |        ...        |       ...       |
```

What I now want to have is, that when I do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE name = 'Kim';
```

- Data from the raw table should be queried, i.e. get all byte[] arrays;
- Deserialize the data to get (name, address, phone) from raw data;
- Apply any conditions, i.e. name = 'Kim'
- Return this set of results to user as if they just simply queried the Person table.

For de-serialisation/transformation etc, I am guessing I may need some programming language functions, so for Java something such as [Pl/Java](http://wiki.tada.se/index.php?title=Writing_Java_functions,_triggers,_and_types) may be useful?

Also, you can assume the Raw-data table will not be very long, it’s implemented to act as a fixed size buffer, so it’s not much of a problem to read all entries for each query.

Conceptually, what I need is a trigger function, but seems we cannot have a trigger on READ. Any help about how I can go about this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That database design seems totally broken to me. You are trying to re-implement a RDBMS by mis-using a RDBMS.

But if you insist on using this design, the only way I can think of is to write a set returning function that does all the processing and unpacking of the raw data in a procedural way. Depending on the complexity of your binary data, PL/pgSQL might be enough.

You would then do a `SELECT * FROM retrieve_person()` to get the output you want.

Comment: What would suggest is a better design? The idea is that the raw data table is constantly updated with events. And instead of populated each separate data-set every time this happens, I want to reverse the process: i.e. only get and transform data when the user asks. So I thought I should implement the datasets as views that are applied on the raw-data table. What would be a better design to this problem?

Comment: A lot of work has gone in to making Postgres quite efficient at storing and retrieving data; it appears that you are trying to do the same thing.  Try storing your data in standard strings and see how fast that goes.  You'll actually gain speed on retrieval, as you will just be querying data, not transforming it.

Comment: @Larry: why not create the person table as you have shown us? If you can't do that, it seems a relational database is not the right choice for you. You might want to store your raw data as XML and then only use different XSLT transformations instead

Comment: @Aaron: But the problem is the raw data are actually xml/html documents coming from feeds. So, either each time a new feed is received I can transform and put into the respective data-stores, or I can just put in as raw, and wait for users to request data when they need. I thought the second would be more efficient, that’s why I have the design I have. But given this explanation, what better technique could I use?

Comment: As the feeds come in, parse each XML doc to and persist the data to your table.  Keep all the transformation stuff in your client app, and use Postgres to store and supply the transformed data.

Comment: @Aaron: this can certainly work, but it means that I have to parse each and every feed that comes in, and more so, always store the data. There are two problems: (a) say I have 100 feeds coming in per minute I am worried this may take too long to process; (b) users may just want the latest set of feed, so if I limit the size of raw-data like a queue this seems a good way, and then users can just ask for data on demand.